# htlatex does not give good results

Tags: tex4ht, html, latex2html, htlatex

I have a very nicely formatted file that I created using LaTeX. Now, I'm trying to embed the results into a website, and instead of embedding the resulting pdf document (which I found not to be as straightforward), I thought I could give a try to htlatex. But the results are terrible, not at all what I expected. Some symbols disappeared, sections with underline titles have the line after the titles (instead than from the beginning), space between bullets is all messed up, tables look bad (for two column tables, there are three lines, instead of only the center one), etc.

I really don't know how to put a minimal sample here, as it is a whole document and I can see formatting issues all over the place. I could possibly take pictures and embed them here if you need more info. But I thought there has to be something I'm doing wrong. I'm just running

```
htlatex filename.tex
```

Is there anything else I should do besides this? Should I be careful on which packages I include in the LaTeX file?

Comment: `tex4ht` cannot convert visual appearance of your document, it only tries to convert document structure with some default style. if you want something more fancy, you can use custom config file and provide CSS here to match your desired style.

Comment: regarding missing characters, could you please post sample document with these missing symbols?

Comment: @michal.h21 if it will only convert the document structure, and I have to apply CSS to match the style, why would I use this tool in the first place? Am I not better off using CSS from scratch?
For the symbols, both the \Letter and \Mundus from the marvosym package do not show up.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon because there is no tool which can convert latex to html preserving appearance and tex4ht is best in preserving structure and ability to configure almost everything. if you want to preserve visual appearance, you can use some pdf to html converter, but you will loose document structure then

Comment: With no demo showing particular issues, I don't see we can hope to answer here.